# Passing a pointer to a structure

Tags: c++, c, pointers, structure

Hi 
 I have a function `A ( xy * abc)` that takes a pointer to a structure.

```
typedef struct
{
int a;
char * b;
} xy;

typedef struct
{
xy c;
xy d;
} uv;

uv *sha;
```

If i need to call the function `A` for `c` and `d` using `uv` how should I pass the argument? I am calling function `A` by using this:

```
A (&sha->c);
A (&sha->d);
```

Is this call correct?

Kindly help me

Comment: @user: Have you tried to compile and execute your program? Is there anything that does not work as you expect? Perhaps a compiler error, or weird runtime-behavior? If so, please explain it in your question.

Comment: It is not throwing any compiler error.. but the function A is not behaving the way it should behave.. thats why :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `uv` is a struct, and not a pointer to struct, you need to do `A(&uv.c)`, but in your case, `uv` is a struct type, not an actual struct, you need to have a variable of type uv:

```
uv somevar;
A(&somevar.c);
```

Comment: sorry my problem description was wrong.. corrected.. kinly help me no.w.

Comment: please do not change the question, but add clarification. And yes, this is the way, the only thing missing is an actual struct, you only have a pointer to a struct, not a struct.

Comment: ...or if there's a pointer to a `uv` object - e.g. `uv* p = new uv();` - then it would be `A(&(p->c))`...

Comment: Hmm yeah.. i have pointer to a structure  sha.. If i need to call to use function A how should i call.. A(&sha->c)?

Comment: @MByD: yes, but the code as presented was wrong so you have to look at the potential deltas to get it working: 1) question mentions pointers and attempts to use `->` in the call, so OP might want to follow a pointer to an object, or 2) what you've covered in your answer. (The edits to the question introduce the "sha" pointer, confirming 1) is the intention.)  user611469: do make sure to assign `sha` to point at an actual object... :-).

Comment: @Tony - I got you. Thanks for both comments. :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a variable of type `uv` then pass it to the function:

```
uv var; 
A(&(var.c));
```

`A(xy*)`  --> takes addres of an object of type `xy`
`var.c`   --> returns object of type `xy`
`&var.c`  --> returns address of returned `xy` object

```
uv *sha;
A(&(sha->c));
A(&(sha->d));
```

`A(xy*)`     --> takes addres of an object of type `xy`
`sha->c`     --> returns object of type `xy`
`&(sha->c)`  --> returns address of returned `xy` object

Comment: I think you meant `xy` in a few places that you wrote `uv`. Besides - nice answer(+1).

Comment: @MByD: Thanks! Those were some gross typos, rendering the answer comletely meaningless..I changed those :)

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems correct, but I will do it like this:

```
A (&(sha->c));
A (&(sha->d));
```

Note the additional parantheses; these are there to add more verbosity although compiler probably won't need those.